# Magento2 - How to save customer address attribute value in database and show on edit of reorder/new order?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-attribute, customer-address

How to save customers address attribute value in the database and show on the edit page when we reorder/new order?

- Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/r7w5d5.

It's working when I update an already placed order(Value update).

Click on order then open order details and then click on `billing/shipping` address and update that custom field then it's work.

But then I click on REorder/ new order of that then value not showing in the newly created order that field is blanked.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This Following Two Method With Related Factory..

public function saveaddress(\Customapi\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $parameters)
    {
        // echo json_encode($parameters);exit;
        // print_r($parameters);
        // $postcode = isset($parameters ['postcode'])?$parameters ['postcode']:0;
        if ($parameters && $parameters->getData()) {
            $data=$parameters->getData();
            // echo json_encod($data);exit;
            if (!isset($data['email']) || !$data['email']) {
                $data = array (
                    'data' => array (
                        'customer' => array (
                            array (
                                'message' => 'email paremer is missing.',
                                'status' => 'false' 
                            ) 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                );
                return [$data];
            }
            if (isset($data['customer_id']) && $data['customer_id'])
               $data['customer']= $data['customer_id'];
           // echo json_encod($data);exit;
            else {
                $data = array (
                    'data' => array (
                        'customer' => array (
                            array (
                                'message' => 'some paremer is missing.',
                                'status' => 'false' 
                            ) 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                );
                return [$data];
            }
            $address = $this->account->saveCustomerAddress($data);
            // echo json_encod($address);exit;
            return [$address];
        } else {
            $data = array (
                'data' => array (
                    'customer' => array (
                        array (
                            'message' => 'some paremer is missing.',
                            'status' => 'false' 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
            );
            return [$data];
        }

```
}
```

public function savebillingshipping(\Customapi\Api\Data\CheckoutInterface $parameters)
    {
        $enable = $enable = $this->checkEnable();

```
    if ($enable && $parameters && count($parameters->getData())) {
        $deviceObject=$this->checkout->savebillingshiping($parameters->getData());
        return array($deviceObject);
    } else {
        return array(['success' => false]);
    }

}
```